# How do I search for multiple words in a list of sentences with re in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a script which scans my entire music directory and stores it in a list, afterwards I input the keywords of the filename (e.g. numb linkin) and the song plays automatically. I've had some success without regex but I have to use somewhat accurate filename (e.g. 'numb (' for a filename like D:\Music\Numb (official) Linkin Park).

I haven't used the re library much but a friend told me that it might be of help in my case.

This is my code so far that can take a somewhat accurate name of the song and play it. I'd love to know how I can improve it through re library and other means? There might be some glaring deficiencies in the code as I'm still new to this.

```
import os
import time

x = [os.path.join(folderName, filename) for folderName, subfolders,
 filenames in os.walk('D:\Music') for filename in filenames]

def songSearch():
    searchList = []
    print('Enter the name of the song you wanna be played')
    name = str(input())
    searchList = [y for y in x if name in y.lower()]
    return searchList

cat = songSearch()

while len(cat) == 0:
    print('No such song exists \nTry Again \n')
    cat = songSearch()

while len(cat) > 1:
    for songDir in cat:
        print(songDir, '\n')
    print('Multiple songs containing that word, please enter \'completer\' name\n')
    cat = songSearch()

if len(cat) == 1:
    print('Now playing: ', cat[0])
    time.sleep(1)
    os.startfile(cat[0])
```

Comment: What sort of regex features do you want to add?

Comment: I'm not looking for any particular features tbh, just a regex that is able to find multiple words in a string, and being able to return that string.

Comment: You don't need regex for simple substring matching... All you need is to split your input query into a list of substrings (e.g. `["numb", "linkin"]`) and then do a simple `all()` match over the list of your files, i.e. `if all(word in filename for word in word_list): ...`. For a case-insensitive match, I'd suggest to lowercase your file list and the substrings you're searching for.

Comment: Thank you zwer, that worked out just fine :)